# std::vector.size() not working

Tags: c++, vector, size

I have some code involving some vectors, but it refuses to give me the size of the vector:

```
using namespace std;

struct key_stat{
    string USER, url;
    float click_count, post_count, click_cost, post_cost;
    keyword_stat(): USER("") {}
};

class key
{
    private:
    string word;
    vector <key_stat> stats;
public:
    key(string & kw);
    vector <key_stat> get_stats(){return stats;}

};


// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
void search(string & word, vector <key> & keys){
    unsigned int x;
    // getting the x value
    for (x = 0; x < keys.size(); x++){
        if (keys[x].get_word() == word)
            break;
    }
    vector <keyword_stat> t = keys[x].get_stats();
    t.size()
}
```

This does not work:

```
t.size();
```

Is there any reason why?

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: Don't say "does not work".  Tell us what happens.  Does it compile?  Does it give you the wrong size?  What size does it give you?  Why do you think it's giving you the wrong size?

Comment: its compiling but i keep on getting `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.` there is no value given

Comment: my crystal ball says `vector <key_stat>& get_stats()`

Comment: "the Runtime"?  Are you using C++CLI?

Comment: Is there any data in `temp` before you do `temp[x]` on it?

Comment: im using code::blocks, compiling with gcc

Comment: Please post your **entire** code.

Comment: @Eugen, no. temp is a variable that is not in the actual function, except for right now, while im debugging

Comment: so you're trying to index temp when there's nothing in it?  that won't work well.

Comment: but vector.size() should return 0 when its empty

Comment: @Tim: The "Runtime" in the message `This application has requested the Runtime ...` refers to the C runtime library that implements the basic faculties needed to implement the standard libraries. It does not necessarily imply that managed code is running.

Comment: @calccrypto: This compiles? You're assigning a `vector<key_stat>` returned from `get_stats()` to a `vector<keyword_stat>` named `t`. And what is `keyword_stat`? All I see is `key_stat`. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vector's `operator[]` does not do bounds checking.  So, here's what happens:

```
for (x = 0; x < keywords.size(); x++){
    if (keywords[x].get_word() == word)
        break;
}
```

if this doesn't find your `word` in the keywords vector, `x` will be the size of keywords.

```
vector <keyword_stat> t = keywords[x].get_stats();
```

a piece at a time:  `keywords[x]` now reads beyond the end of the vector, returning garbage.  `.get_stats()` attempts to return a vector, but is just getting more garbage.

```
t.size();
```

Now you're calling a function on what is essentially corrupt data.

To fix this, check for `x < keywords.size()` before you use it in `vector::operator[]` -- or just use `vector::at()` which does do bounds checking.